# How to perform background process in android?

Tags: android, service

I am performing some operations(uploading image to webservice) in IntentService.
Please see my code below.

Inside the activity i am calling service like this.
I am calling the below method after capturing the image i.e. inside onActivityResult. The app is getting hanged when i call this method in onActivityResult. I am able to perform the task in IntentService. But the acitivity is getting hanged.

```
private void callService(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestIntentService.class);
    intent.putExtra("imageData", imageData);
    startService(intent);
}
```

This is my IntentService Class.
Can i perform webservice call inside callImageUploadAPI(). 
Am i doing anything wrong here?

```
public class TestIntentService extends IntentService {

    public TestIntentService() {
        super("com.screens.testapp");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
//imageData passed from the activity
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(intent != null){
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        imageData= extras.getString("imageData");
    }
        callImageUploadAPI(imageData);
    }

    private void callImageUploadAPI(final String imageData) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            if (Log.checkNetworkStatus(TestIntentService.this)) {

            } else {

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception

        }
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: You are using INTENTSERVICE  to start your service to acess the webservice, it is automatically run as background process.. Or if u want to acess service in new thread as background process, use AsyncTask.. the web service callig undertaken in doInBackground(params) and result will be in onPostExecute(Result).... Happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you to perform actions in the background use Services.

You can launch the services from your activity and you can assign a thread for the service and a handler for communication from that thread to the UIThread.

Check this: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

A little sneak peek

A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface.

Comment: I had used IntentService for this. Please see my code in the post. Is the code correct?

Comment: I haven´t tried it, but it seems correct although you are not doing anything in the callImageUploadApi add some prints there so you can see if the method is actually beeing called and that the string is what you expect it to be and not a null or something else.

Comment: i am calling the webservice in callImageUploadApi. I cannot share that code that is why i dint mentioned the code in callImageUploadApi.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do a task in background, Android provides a class called `AsyncTask` which you can extend and use it for doing a network operation or any other heavy operation. This is an example from [Android Developer Website (AsyncTask Page):](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

This may be used in your code this way:

```
if (Log.checkNetworkStatus(TestIntentService.this)) {
               new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
            } else {

            }
```

Comment: Thanksfor giving reply. But i want to perform this task in background. User can be able to perform other tasks in foreground.

Comment: @ravi the method `doInBackground` of AsyncTask class provides you with this facility. You can do any task you want to do in background in the body of this method.

Comment: i cannot use Progress dialog while the task is running in the background. User has to perform operations(button click or entering some data) while the task is running in the background.

Comment: @ravi I understand what you are trying to say. You need to perform a silent background operation. Right? So Yes, my provided solution will work even if you want to perform a silent operation. Don't show any progress dialog.

Comment: I had tried with your code. Firstly i am capturing an image. I am calling this method in onActivityResult method after the image is captured. What i have seen is that the app is getting hanged when i call the background task in onActiviyResult.

Comment: @ravi Can you please edit your question and add the code you tried? Thanks.